# why does the thread get the demo.names is null?

Tags: c#, multithreading

here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("---------" + i.ToString());
            Demo.TestError();
        }
    }

    public class Demo
    {
        public Demo() { }

        public Demo(int i) { index = i; }

        public static void TestError()
        {
            List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
            Demo demo = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                if (i % 10 == 0)
                {
                    demo = new Demo(i);
                }
                #region code1
                Thread t = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    demo.SetName();
                    var names = demo.names;
                    string msg = null;
                    if (names == null)
                    {
                        msg = demo.index.ToString() + " -" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString() + "-is null";
                        Console.Write(msg);
                    }
                    else if (names == null || names.Count <= 0)
                    {
                        msg = demo.index.ToString() + " -" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString() + "-is zero";
                        Console.Write(msg);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        msg = demo.index.ToString() + " -" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString() + "-is ok" + "-" + string.Join(",", names);
                    }
                });
                t.Start();
                #endregion
                threads.Add(t);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < threads.Count; i++)
            {
                threads[i].Join();
            }
        }

        public List<string> names;

        public int index;

        public object lockObj = new object();

        public void SetName()
        {
            if (names == null)
            {
                lock (lockObj)
                {
                    if (names == null)
                    {
                        var tnames = new List<string>();
                        tnames.Add("a");
                        System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref names, tnames, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

run it, and it shows(partial) :

> ---------60 750 -747-is null---------61
>   ---------62
>
> ...
>
> ---------95 960 -5174-is null---------96
>   ---------97
>
> ...
>
> ---------101 580 -3591-is null---------102
>   ---------103
>
> ...
>
> ---------112 720 -2193-is null---------113
>   ---------114
>
> ...
>
> ---------123 50 -2790-is null---------124
>   ---------125
>
> ...
>
> ---------133 420 -1237-is null---------134
>   ---------135
>
> ...

change code1 to code2:

```
                #region code2
                Thread t = new Thread((obj) =>
                {
                    var d = obj as Demo;
                    d.SetName();
                    var names = d.names;
                    ...//the same as above
                });
                t.Start(demo);
                #endregion
```

it runs success! so what's the difference between

```
public Thread(ThreadStart start);
```

and

```
public Thread(ParameterizedThreadStart start);
```

? and why `demo.names` is null or its'count is zero?

Answer (score 1):

They're only different in that `ParameterizedThreadStart` gets an object as the input but `ThreadStart` doesn't, simple as that.

So why one of them works and the other doesn't? It's because of your variable scope. Once you use `ParameterizedThreadStart` it passes the `demo` variable as a parameter so when the `for` loop iterates to the next run, it doesn't change its reference, whereas in the first code you're using the same object and sharing it among all the threads.

The main problem being you've defined the `demo` variable outside the `for` block.So a race condition is occurring as you're changing the reference of the variable (demo) briskly in the loop, whereas it's still being used in your threads.

```
Demo demo = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
  if (i % 10 == 0)
  {
     demo = new Demo(i);
  }
  ...
}
```

if you change your code to this, it should get fixed and work in both scenarios :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
  Demo demo = null;
  if (i % 10 == 0)
  {
     demo = new Demo(i);
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: thank you, I know why code2 works but code1 do not, code1 is transfered by 'reference' and code2 is transfered by 'value', so code2 is 'thread safe' (the demo is shared in 10 threads), but code1 is shared in all 1000 threads! 
but I wonder why code1 gets the demo.names == null? 
In Demo.SetName(), I has used lock to avoid the thread race, even sharing in 1000 threads, it should work well, but in act it doesn't work, could you tell me why?

Comment: You're welcome, Your lock is inside the threads so it just blocks the code within the threads' codes. Notice that the line `demo = new Demo(i);` is outside the thread. and it's got no lock on it. and the demo variable is shared everywhere so when it creates a new instance, `demo.names` gets null.

Answer (score 0):

I know why code1 gets the demo.names == null, in

```
                if (i % 10 == 0)
                {
                    demo = new Demo(i);
                }
                #region code1
                Thread t = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    demo.SetName();
                    var names = demo.names;
```

when thread1 runs to demo.SetName(), it sets the demo.names not null, but thread2 runs to the demo = new Demo(i), it sets the demo.names null, then var names = demo.names it gets the demo.names null, but now demo is a different instance with demo.SetName().
@akazemis thank you!